# How to choose network in latest version (2.1.8.0105) of Mouse without borders?

Tags: windows-10, mouse

I just updated to the latest version of MWB and now I cannot choose the network or check the TCP checkbox.

Does anybody know if that is possible in this version? Or maybe am I missing something?

I ask because it has never worked with default settings and now I cannot change that settings.

Any ideas?

**Actual version**
[image: Here it is the menu in the latest version]

**Previous version**
[image: Here it is the menu in all previous versions]